# For which values of t is the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The 3 vectors are $v_1 = (2, -3, 1)~~ v_2 = (-4, 6, -2)~~ v_3 = (t, 1, 2)$

So I put them all into a 3x3 matrix. Calculated the determinant, which came to $0$. So surely they're dependent? Or am I doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: Looks like $v_2=-2v_1$, so they’re dependent no matter what $t$ is

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing something wrong.

$v_2=-2v_1$, so $v_1, v_2, $ (and $v_3$) are linearly dependent no matter what $t$ is.